# What adhesive or glue should I use to attach velcro to PVC pipe?

Tags: pvc

I have some vertical standing pvc pipes that I want to attach velcro to.  I wish to hang some fabric from the velcro, and thus there will be some forces pulling the velcro from the pvc.  I've already tried using 3M Rubber & Vinyl Spray Adhesive, and it worked for a while, but has since fallen off.

Can you suggest a better way to attach the Velcro and PVC?

Comment: What is the PVC used for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an adhesive suggestion for you, but **you could use [hose clamps](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=hose+clamp&x=0&y=0)**. Put one on the top and one on the bottom of a rectangular section of velcro and clamp it onto the pipe. (Make sure to not over-tighten it.)

Actually, if you could work up a way to attach the fabric to the hose clamps and skip the velcro altogether, that would cut your hose clamp needs by half. They'd be around a buck at the hardware store.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  I need the velcro however, as the fabric has to be taunt as I'm using it for a green screen (can't have any wrinkles in it).

Comment: Ummm  new information about the application.  How about some tight bungee cords to keep the fabric tight?  Bungee the top, sides and bottom to keep it taught.??????

Comment: That seemed to do the trick Thx! :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use either a few daps of a urethane based adhesive such as PL200 or PL400, or if the velcro has a plastic backing, a little PVC pipe glue may work well. Just be sure to clean the surface of the PVC pipe well before using any adhesive.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want long-term durability, glues generally aren't going to cut it. You could try riveting the velcro in place using pop rivets--put a flexible washer or sew a grommet on the velcro to reinforce it.

Comment: Keep in mind this is OK if the PVC is just being used as a frame. If its actually plumbing then using rivets is a bad idea, puts a hole in the pipe that then has to be sealed up.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I was assuming framing given the nature of the task, but that's not guaranteed...

Comment: @Freiheit and Alex it's just a frame, but that's a good point, just incase someone else reads this question.

Comment: @leeand00 - edit your original post to clarify that it is a PVC frame and not plubming

Answer (score 3):

You might try using [Industrial Strength Velcro](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=industrial+strength+velcro&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=13440850699595671951&ei=ktEgTemqHoGB8gaZkYSWDg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q8wIwAA#). It comes with a very strong adhesive backing. To ensure it doesn't peel over time, consider using cable ties or hose clamps at the ends.

Comment: That's actually the Velcro that I am using!  I remember because it has the Hammer velcroed to the wall on the package!

The adhesive on the back (along with the 3M Rubber & Vinyl adhesive stuck for around a year, but lost it's since lost it's stickiness.

Answer (score 3):

PVC pipes are very smooth. I'd rough up the surface with coarse sandpaper before sticking the velcro (or using adhesives).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have it. Use Sikaflex, any grade, I use marine 491 but they are all extremely strong flexible adhesive sealants.

If you don't have that trade name in your country look for 3M 5200 or any polyurathande adhesive sealant. Used extensively in the marine and building industries.

Its a lot cheaper buying the industrial stuff, which ironically is what the guys in the marine trade often use, saying its almost exactly if not exactly the same stuff.

Be careful of fingers, the stuff gets everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

System 3 T-88 epoxy, roughen up the pvc pipe first, and let it cure for24hours